# Javascript - ReferenceError: agevalue is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I am a bit confused with my code, let me explain:

Everything is working correctly except the last bit of code, I am struggling to understand why?
When I try my code, the debugger is telling me

> "ReferenceError: agevalue is not defined"

I understand what does that mean but I don't understand why...
Let me explain quickly what I want if it's not obvious: I have a DOM attached to the Javascript, I would like to import into a paragraph the value/values (dietvalue, age value,familyvalue...) bigger or equal to 10.

As I am student and this is part of my exam, I am not expecting the exact answer but more a clue or a way to fix it. By the way I know my code could be improved but I really want to finish it before to start improve it.

Thank you for your help!

```
window.onload=changeElement;

function changeElement() { 
   document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = myFunction
}


function myFunction() {
        var agevalue;
        var radiobuttons = document.getElementsByName("age");
         for (var i = 0; i < radiobuttons.length; i++) {

             if (radiobuttons[i].checked == true) {
                 agevalue = radiobuttons[i].value;
             }
         }                  

        var bmivalue;
        var radiobuttons = document.getElementsByName("bmi");
         for (var i = 0; i < radiobuttons.length; i++) {

             if (radiobuttons[i].checked == true) {
                 bmivalue = radiobuttons[i].value;
             }
         }

        var familyvalue;
        var radiobuttons = document.getElementsByName("family background");
         for (var i = 0; i < radiobuttons.length; i++) {

             if (radiobuttons[i].checked == true) {
                 familyvalue = radiobuttons[i].value;
             }
         }

        var dietvalue;
        var radiobuttons = document.getElementsByName("diet");
         for (var i = 0; i < radiobuttons.length; i++) {

             if (radiobuttons[i].checked == true) {
                 dietvalue = radiobuttons[i].value;
             }
         }
         var total = parseInt(agevalue) + parseInt(bmivalue) + parseInt(familyvalue) + parseInt(dietvalue);

         if (total <=15){
         document.getElementById("results").innerHTML= "Result 1"; }

         if (total >=16 && total <=25){
         document.getElementById("results").innerHTML= "Result 2"; }

         if (total >25){
         document.getElementById("results").innerHTML= "Result 3" ; } 
                    }   


     if (parseInt(agevalue) >= 10 || parseInt(bmivalue) >= 10 || parseInt(familyvalue) >= 10 || parseInt(dietvalue) >= 10);
     {
        document.getElementById("risks").innerHTML= "Your risks are: "

     }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you create a Fiddle? That would be easier to diagnose and help you. By looking your code 1 possible issue might be that if you do not check any radio button for a group, that value will hold `undefined` and `parseInt` will throw error. Also always use distinct variable names. You have defined `radiobuttons` multiple times

Comment: Try to reduce your code to exactly what is not working. Doing this you'll probably find and fix the error. Also, `debugger` and all the debugging tools are your friends!

Comment: Do you know on which line the error occurs? The error can be as easy as there is no age checkbox checked and then then there will be no assignment to `agevalue` as there is no default value set.

Comment: *Important*: you should also always specify the second parameter 10 to the `parseInt` function as `parseInt(x, 10)` otherwize it will treat you input as hexadecimal which means that `string "10"` will become `number 16` (not so obvious bug in your code) Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: You have an extra `}` on the "Result 3" near the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your last `if` condition is outside the `myFunction` where the variable `agevalue` is defined. try putting it inside the `myfunction` and check or you will have to declare that variable outside this method (in a global context).

i.e.

```
function myFunction() {
        var agevalue;
        var radiobuttons = document.getElementsByName("age");
         for (var i = 0; i < radiobuttons.length; i++) {

             if (radiobuttons[i].checked == true) {
                 agevalue = radiobuttons[i].value;
             }
         }                  

        var bmivalue;
        var radiobuttons = document.getElementsByName("bmi");
         for (var i = 0; i < radiobuttons.length; i++) {

             if (radiobuttons[i].checked == true) {
                 bmivalue = radiobuttons[i].value;
             }
         }

        var familyvalue;
        var radiobuttons = document.getElementsByName("family background");
         for (var i = 0; i < radiobuttons.length; i++) {

             if (radiobuttons[i].checked == true) {
                 familyvalue = radiobuttons[i].value;
             }
         }

        var dietvalue;
        var radiobuttons = document.getElementsByName("diet");
         for (var i = 0; i < radiobuttons.length; i++) {

             if (radiobuttons[i].checked == true) {
                 dietvalue = radiobuttons[i].value;
             }
         }
         var total = parseInt(agevalue) + parseInt(bmivalue) + parseInt(familyvalue) + parseInt(dietvalue);

         if (total <=15){
         document.getElementById("results").innerHTML= "Result 1"; }

         if (total >=16 && total <=25){
         document.getElementById("results").innerHTML= "Result 2"; }

         if (total >25){
         document.getElementById("results").innerHTML= "Result 3" ; } 

if (parseInt(agevalue) >= 10 || parseInt(bmivalue) >= 10 || parseInt(familyvalue) >= 10 || parseInt(dietvalue) >= 10);
     {
        document.getElementById("risks").innerHTML= "Your risks are: "

     }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run it through http://jshint.com/
you get

```
Four undefined variables
57  agevalue
57  bmivalue
57  familyvalue
57  dietvalue
```

jshint is a useful tool to use.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `agevalue` inside the `for` loop:

```
var agevalue;
var radiobuttons = document.getElementsByName("age");
 for (var i = 0; i < radiobuttons.length; i++) {

     if (radiobuttons[i].checked == true) {
         agevalue = radiobuttons[i].value;
     }
 }
```

But what if there are no checked radio button elements with the name *"age"*?
Then its value is `undefined`.

I believe this is the case in your application.

You may want to give it a default value, e.g. 1.

```
var agevalue = 1;
```